# How to code parameters for a MTF strategy v5 pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am currently doing a multi time frame MA indicator but encountered a problem when turning it into a strategy so I can use my brute force optimiser. The strategy uses 4hr MA's on the 5 or 15 minutes depending on the currency/commodity.

I did not code in any parameters on the indicator therefore cannot optimise it automatically and have to do it manually.

Below is my code if someone can guide me through what to write, it would be very appreciated

```
indexHighTf = barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0
indexCurrTf = barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1

x_timeframe = request.security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, timeframe='240', expression=close[indexHighTf])[indexCurrTf]

y_timeframe = request.security(symbol=syminfo.tickerid, timeframe='48', expression=close[indexHighTf])[indexCurrTf]

plot(x_timeframe, color=color.new(color.blue,0))
plot(y_timeframe, color=color.new(color.purple, 0))

goLong() => ta.crossover(y_timeframe, x_timeframe)
goShort() => ta.crossunder(y_timeframe, x_timeframe)
```

Comment: What parameters do you want to have?

Comment: It's a double SMA strategy, I'd like to use 4hr settings on the 5 and 15 minutes. 1 MA will be 48 on the 4hrs so 240 on the 5 mins and the second is a 1 MA on the 4hrs so 48 on the 5 minutes. But i'd like the strategy to keep in mind these are 4hr values on a smaller TF. BTW you are a lifesaver Vitruvius i really appreciate the help you've been providing me in the recent weeks!!